# Fragment transition with sharedElements stopped working on Anrdoid 9

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I have a recycler view -> details view flow. Transition names are unique within the list and match transition  names in the details fragment. Two views are supposed to be moved instead of faded in/out like everything else. My animations were working properly until I have changed target API to 26.  On API 26 shared views jump to their "end" state without any animations. Everything else is property animated.

I have tried to follow several guides to no avail. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
private fun showDetails(edited: EditedAlarm) {
    fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment_container)?.lollipop {
        exitTransition = Fade()
    }

    val detailsFragment = AlarmDetailsFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle()
        arguments.putInt(Intents.EXTRA_ID, edited.id())
        arguments.putBoolean(Store.IS_NEW_ALARM, edited.isNew)
    }.lollipop {
        val enterSlide = Slide()

        if (edited.holder.isPresent()) {
            val viewHolder = edited.holder.get()
            enterSlide.epicenterCallback = viewHolder.epicenter()
            enterSlide.slideEdge = Gravity.TOP
        }

        enterTransition = TransitionSet().addTransition(enterSlide).addTransition(Fade())

        val move = TransitionInflater.from(this@AlarmsListActivity).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
        sharedElementEnterTransition = move
        sharedElementReturnTransition = move
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .lollipop {
                val viewHolder = edited.holder.get()
                addSharedElement(viewHolder.digitalClock(), viewHolder.digitalClock.transitionName)
                addSharedElement(viewHolder.container(), viewHolder.container().transitionName)
            }
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, detailsFragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I have found the solution:

Use SupportFragmentManager from the support library. Even though Fragments are not deprecated in API Version 26, they do not always work.